# Issues with PHP and World Database: Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So I'm creating some PHP connected to the World database (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html). I'm getting an error that says: Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment11\exercise2.php on line 12 Connection failed: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

This is for an assignment that said to:

> Write a PHP script that uses the  world database and
> shows all the countries stored in the country table and
> shows all the songs that include the string "island" in the Name field

I don't have any password set so I'm just a little confused. I'm using Visual Studio Code and Xampp (I have Apache and MySQL turned on in the Xampp Control Panel, I have tried to refresh the tab multiple times having just one module or the other on, still no luck). Any assistance would be great, thank you!

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "world";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<br>". $row["Name"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "world";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE Name LIKE '%island%';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br>". $row["Name"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you wrote two html pages ,and it should only be one php script

Comment: You need to create a user and then login via that user

Comment: or use the rpoot account and set the passwort https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html

Comment: Yeah I know that the world database is functioning, I checked it out through the shell in the Xampp control panel and it's functioning as it should be. I just put in both scripts I wrote, they are not in the same file.